# Short story where a man is stranded on an island on another planet and records messages for his future self

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There's this one short story where some people or some guy gets stranded on an island on another planet. He starts recording messages for himself so when he's old and senile he's basically making fun of himself for being an old man who doesn't know anything.

Comment: The "another planet" does qualify this as sci-fi, just for those who might have the same kneejerk reaction as me. :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a bit short; you should review the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good question to see if they help you remember any additional details to [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be Ray Bradbury's short story ["Night Call, Collect"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58411), which centers on an old man on Mars being tormented by messages recorded by his younger self.

> "Impossible!" The voice of the young Barton laughed, far away. "I've no way to tell if you ever get this call. This is all mechanical. You're talking to a transcription, no more. This is 2037. Sixty years in your past. Today, the atom war started on Earth. All colonials were called home from Mars, by rocket. I got left behind!"
>
> "I remember." whispered the old man.

Comment: The collection [*I Sing the Body Electric*](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL14461092M/I_sing_the_body_electric!) (1974 edition), which contains the story, is available to borrow from the [Open Library](https://openlibrary.org).

Comment: "Night Call, Collect" also went by the title "I, Mars" in at least one anthology.  As I recall the man had programmed the system to answer calls from his real self until he reached a certain age, after that it could start calling him.